# Add auto index change after function load or after specific timer

Tags: flutter, dart

Anyone know how to increase index stacking count to make it auto change to next widget? I wanted it to change after a set amount of time for example 5 sec, or any way to make the index change one the widget has properly loaded? I am trying to stack splashscreen and webview using index because currently there is white screen in between after splash and first widget which is webview. i provided my code for review

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

class InAppView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InAppViewState createState() => _InAppViewState();
}

class _InAppViewState extends State<InAppView> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;
  String url = "";
  double progress = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: IndexedStack(
        index: 0,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/splash.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill)),
          ),
          InAppWebView(
            initialUrl: "https://flutter.dev/",
            initialHeaders: {},
            initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
              debuggingEnabled: true,
            )),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code. This will help you. But for this, you need to first import the [Connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) package into your pubspec.yaml file

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

class InAppView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _InAppViewState();
  }
}

class _InAppViewState extends State<InAppView> {
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    subscription = Connectivity()
        .onConnectivityChanged
        .listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      if (result != ConnectivityResult.none && webView != null) {
        _loadError = false;
        webView.reload();
      }
    });
  }

  num position = 1;

  final key = UniqueKey();

  doneLoading(String A) {
    setState(() {
      position = 0;
    });
  }

  startLoading(String A) {
    setState(() {
      position = 1;
    });
  }

  InAppWebViewController webView;
  int _page = 2;
  bool _loadError = false;
  StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> subscription;

  @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    subscription.cancel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _page,
        children: <Widget>[
          InAppWebView(
            initialUrl: "https://flutter.dev/",
            initialHeaders: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
            },
            initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
              debuggingEnabled: true,
            )),
            onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
              webView = controller;
            },
            onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {},
            onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {
              setState(() {
                if (!_loadError) {
                  _page = 0;
                } else {
                  _page = 1;
                }
              });
            },
            onLoadError: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url,
                int code, String message) async {
              print("error $url: $code, $message");
              _loadError = true;
            },
            onLoadHttpError: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url,
                int statusCode, String description) async {
              print("HTTP error $url: $statusCode, $description");
            },
          ),
          Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Text("Some error occured !!"),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This code is what I am looking for.